# Any hack to get cell id on iPhone 3.0?

Tags: iphone, cell, telephony

There was a hack for previous firmware using a reverse engineering of Code Telephony but it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only get the UDID on the iphone.

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier
```

*A unique device identifier is a hash value composed from various hardware identifiers such as the device’s serial number. It is guaranteed to be unique for every device but cannot publically be tied to a user account. You can use it, for example, to store high scores for a game in a central server or to control access to registered products. The unique device identifier is sometimes referred to by its abbreviation UDID.*